# Annoying file system check, when starting the computer with WOL

Tags: filesystem, remote-access

Sometimes I need to get some files from my desktop computer, so I send a wake on LAN package (using my laptop) to the computer and it turns on. But every 30 times I have to wait ~30 minutes for the file system check (and I can't cancel it through SSH or so).

Many people would like to move the file system check to shutdown, but these projects and ideas seem to be quite abandoned:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AutoFsck
https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/prompt-for-fsck-on-shutdown
http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/11021/

I tried to use AutoFsck, but I did not succeed to get it work with LightDM - see: [Run a script with user interaction on log out / shutdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152118/run-a-script-with-user-interaction-on-log-out-shutdown)

Maybe somebody has a different idea for an work a round?

**Disabling the file system check is not an option for me.**

Answer (score 0):

I changed mine to run once every month with this command:

`tune2fs -i 1m /dev/sda1`

You can find your device name with the `mount` command.

Comment: I thought about this. But I decided that it is not even worth to run this one command, since 30 boots is nearly the same as every month... ;) Thanks for your hint anyway!

Comment: So change it to whatever period you want. Or disable it with tune2fs, and run it manually once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

I added a little more detail for the ' Run a script with user interaction on log out / shutdown?' 
ideas on how to make it work through lightdm and posted those ideas here: [Run a script with user interaction on log out / shutdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152118/run-a-script-with-user-interaction-on-log-out-shutdown/527648#527648)

Basically, you can prompt the user (or just go ahead and do AutoFsck without prompting) on lightdm shutdown.  The bottom line is block shutdown with a small init.d script that checks for a flag (i.e. file or contents of a file, like number of reboots) that is set and removed by your AutoFsck calling script. This way AutoFsck will definitely start and finish and the system will only shutdown once AutoFsck finishes.  With this script tandem, you can disable automatic file system checks in tune2fs because you implemented 'automatic' AutoFsck via lightdm or any other process you choose.