# Logout scripts: not completed on shutdown, reboot

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, lightdm, logout, scripts

I'm trying to do some stuff at logout, and the task can take up to 5 minutes to complete.

If the user chooses `Power off` or `Reboot` directly, the script is killed before completion. If the user just chooses `Log out`, the script is executed with no problems.

I've tried using `pam_exec` and `lightdm` property `session-cleanup-script` to point to my script, but it's the same in both cases.

The script used to do the testing is this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /tmpfile
for p in $(seq 0 300) ; do
    sleep 1
    echo $p >> /tmpfile
done
```

When logging out, all the 300 numbers are written to the file. When shutting down or rebooting directly from within the user session, only 2 or 3 numbers are written, so the script is being killed.

How is handled the shutdown by lightdm? How can I ensure my script is not being killed?

If you propose an alternative approach, please take care that I need to know what user is being logged out and be able to run a script as that user. I also need to notify the user about what's happening, so better stay on X if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle this, I combined three mechanisms:

- A Lightdm logout script, that gets the user information and writes it on a temporary file, so we can know who is powering off the computer. It also does the heavy task in case we're not shutting down or rebooting.
- Traditional initrd scripts to do the heavy tasks when shutting down or rebooting.
- Plymouth status messages to give feedback about that heavy tasks when shutting down or rebooting.

So, I have the heavy task script on `/usr/local/bin/heavy.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash 
touch /tmpfile 
for p in $(seq 0 300) ; do
    sleep 1
    echo $p >> /tmpfile
    if [ ! -z $DISPLAY ] ; then
        notify-send "Written $p"
    else 
        plymouth message --text="Written $p" &>/dev/null
    fi
done
```

That heavy task tries to output information to X. If that fails, tries to do it to Plymouth.

Then, I added this line to the Lightdm configuration on `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`:

```
session-cleanup-script=/usr/local/sbin/logout-tasks.sh
```

The referenced script writes down the user on logout and tries to do the heavy task:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $USER > /run/last-logout-user
/usr/local/bin/heavy.sh
```

The initrd script, located on `/etc/init.d/logout-heavy-task-at-shutdown`:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER_RUN=$(cat /run/last-logout-user)
sudo -u $USER_RUN /usr/local/bin/heavy.sh
```

That launches the task as the last logged out user when shutting down and restarting, considering we add the corresponding links:

```
 update-rc.d -n logout-heavy-task-at-shutdown start 05 0
 update-rc.d -n logout-heavy-task-at-shutdown start 05 6
```

And that's it. The heavy task might need to handle when it's killed by X and then launched again by the initrd script. Depending on the task, that might not be a problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu, scripts for different runlevels are executed according to their presence in the `/etc/rc[0-6].d` directories. `Runlevel 0` corresponds to shutdown, and 6 to reboot.

Typically the script is stored in `/etc/init.d`, and then symlinks are placed in the directories corresponding to the runlevels you require.

So in your case, write your script, store it in `/etc/init.d/`, then create a symlink in each of `/etc/rc0.d` and `/etc/rc6.d` (if you want both) pointing to your script.

Create a symlink like: `/etc/rc0.d/K01myscipt -> /etc/init.d/myscript`

The scripts in each runlevel directory will be executed in ASCIIbetical order, so if the order within the runlevel matters to you, choose the name of your symlink accordingly.

Hope that solves it. Don't forget to 
make it executable (sudo chmod +x myscript). Also,  I'm not sure, but maybe you'll have to cancel shutdown at the beginning of the script - `shutdown -c now` and issue it again at the end - `shutdown -h now`.

Now to know,  who issued the `shutdown` command :
1) Either, Well, you can do that with the help of wrapper script as follow:

`a. mv /sbin/shutdown /sbin/shutdown-orig`
`b. vim /sbin/shutdown
     #!/bin/sh
     echo "$USER has initiated the shutdown process" >> /var/log/shutdown.owner
     /sbin/shutdown-orig "$@"`
`c. chmod 755 /sbin/shutdown`

2) Or, a normal user only has access to the `shutdown` command via `sudo` and `sudo` commands are (typically) logged under `/var/log/`. So, you can check that. Hope it helps.
For further information, kindly refer to [my thread here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107501/shutdown-log-linux-username/107510?noredirect=1#107510). Don't forget to stop by and say Thanks to them.

EDIT: Concluding, If nothing works, Try using sudo and walling off access to shutdown/reboot and then only you can check for logs and know who initiated the shutdown process. Detail's in content below. Thanks. `Wonderful Question, Learnt a Lot.`

Comment: This won't allow us to know which user is shutting down the system. Am I wrong?

Comment: imho, consider adding `who` and getting the output on print statement that will let you know currently logged in users, or else, doing `tail /var/log/auth.log | grep "username"` should give you a user's sudo history. i don't think there is a way to get a unified command history of a user's normal + sudo commands.

Comment: you can use `$USER` variable to determine user

Comment: In that case as c0rp says, that can be done.

Comment: @ASCIIbetical I thought when those shutdown scripts run the users are already logged out, so there is nothing in the output of `who`. But I've never tried it, so my thought could have been wrong. Now I've tried it, but unfortunately it is the way I thought, no output from `who`. Doing some text searching and filtering in the logs to find out who was logged out last by lightdm might work, but obivously a simple tail-grep pair won't be enough. If you update your answer with a script which does filter out the username (**only the username**) of who clicked  shutdown, that might be a solution.

Comment: @c0rp The same goes for `$USER`, that variable is not set when those shutdown/reboot scripts are run.

Comment: @falconer lemme get back to it asap.

Comment: @ASCIIbetical Have you tested these solutions? Your `1)` solution might work, but I have my doubts with that one (will test it later), and I don't like the idea of replacing such an important system binary with a custom script. That method is prone to failure. Your `2)` solution is for running the `sudo shutdown` command, not for shutting down from the GUI menu, and it still not gives back only the username, but a lot of other info. That solution is basically your previous `tail-grep` pair`, the output still needs filtering, and how to do that filtering is not obvious and prone-to-errors also

Comment: @falconer, While I do agree to what You said in the above comment, I fail to differ in some aspects. While OP & you wish to know & demanded a script for knowing who issued the shutdown cmd, i wrote it and let you guys know to the best of my knowledge. I guess that might work, until unless though i do agree that `replacing such an important system binary with a custom script` isn't a good idea. So & so, That's all i guess. You asked for a script. I gave that to you best of my knowledge. To control activity, I guess option 2 will be most favorable, Just to filter the stuff out from system file.

Comment: @OP, You have to parse the log files mate or else you can use the `script` i provided.

Comment: @ASCIIbetical This question is searching for a solution when the shutdown is initiated from the GUI, not from the terminal. Now I tested your `1)` solution, and unfortunately that one also doesn't work from the GUI shutdown, because the $USER variable is not set. (Because it isn't the user who runs `shutdown` but some system process) You say filter out from system file, but which one? I checked auth.log, there is no log for who started the shutdown. I checked the unix.stackexchange site with your question, and the answers provided there also doesn't help. Which log file should I look at?

Comment: @falconer I guess you are true, parsing system log files wont be any help as `it isn't the user who runs shutdown but some system process`. Also i tried doing the same, I initiated a shutdown at 10:10:34 and started my system at 10:11:16, no username is there. Look here : http://pastebin.com/5g6RpmuM

Comment: @falconer and @OP, So I had a hearty discussion regarding the solution to knowing username who initiated `shutdown` here(http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107501/shutdown-log-linux-username/107510?noredirect=1#comment165478_107510). Much to my wonders, You can't know `user` because there is a interface that catches the signal to shutdown/reboot and then triggers it. This process runs as root so you'll never see a username that way. Using sudo and walling off access to shutdown/reboot is just how sysadmins do this.-from a person who managed a fortune 500 company infrastructure.

Comment: I even tried `scripts` sorry they wont help, parsing `logs` wont help either, only way you can do that is to `using sudo and walling off access to shutdown/reboot`. Letting you know,how to do that, well will be a whole lot another answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: @falconer Kindly shoot if anything else remains coz bounty is ending in just T- 11 hours. :)

Comment: @falconer, Hope everything is good. !

Comment: @ASCIIbetical If you are asking whether I will give the bounty to your answer, then I'm sorry but I won't. While I really do appreciate the work and time you put in your answer (thx for all your efforts) but this answer doesn't solve this problem. The OP and me are searching for a solution for the GUI shutdown, not the terminal one. A solution for this problem would be either identifying the problem why the lightdm logout-scripts fail to complete, or some other method which helps us to run a script just BEFORE the real shutdown sequence is started by lightdm.

Comment: Its Okay. Least I learnt a lot while researching for the same. Have fun.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I finally solved this. Ended up combining the lightdm logout script (to write down the user that turned off the computer on a temporary file) with a traditional sysvinit script that does the hard work. I use plymouth to display status messages and it does the job. I'll try to write an answer later explaining this better.

Answer (score 1):

**LightDM**

Create a script in `/etc/rc0.d`.

```
sudo vim /etc/rc0.d/myScript
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc0.d/myScript
```

**GDM**

Add your command to the file `/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default` before the `exit 0` line.

As before shutdown the user is logged off anyway, this should cover both bases.

Comment: There is no `/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default` file. I'm using `lightdm` for instance. I've created it anyways, but that didn't help. That script is never run.

Comment: See the edit. Should work now..

Comment: I need to know if a user is logging out, and what user, so that won't help.

Comment: Also, it would be better to stay on the an X session, because I need to show some output to the user. I'm adding this information to the main post.